# How can I write different values to different pixels over multiple frames in FFmpeg?

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, steganography

Thanks to Gyan, I know that the geq filter can modify pixels. I have seen expressions that modify a range of pixels; however, I want to iterate through each frame of a video and use my own f(x) for selecting the pixel and an array of color values to write to these pixels.

I know that there exists between() to select a range of frames but I do not want to write the same pixel changes to each frame.

How can I write different values to different pixels over multiple frames?
i.e. Frame 1: set pixel [0, 0] r-value to 255, Frame 2: set pixel [25, 16] g-value to 133, etc.

Comment: This can be done manually, but it will get unwieldy fast. How many pixels in all do you wish to alter?

Comment: ultimately, thousands..if I could get 3 pixels in 3 separate frames with different values, I could at least explain the idea. Can you elaborate on how will it get unwieldy? I have my own f(x) for selecting pixels; however, it is the frame iteration. See, for an image, I select a pixel, write a different value to it, move to the next pixel, etc. For the video, I would write to a frame until I am out of space, and move to the next frame. Then I want to playback the video to view the results. Afterwards, I would try to retrieve the values I wrote to the video, using the f(x) to determine the px

Comment: The basic template is `geq=r='st(1,eq(N,4)*eq(X,342)*eq(Y,84)*123+eq(N,23)*eq(X,113)*eq(Y,459)*165+eq(N,24)*eq(X,3)*eq(Y,273)*16)+p(X,Y)*not(ld(1))'` -> this shows alteration of 3 pixels in 3 different  frames for the R channel. You'll need exprs for G and B as well.

Comment: I would rather do something like this using openCV and not ffmpeg